# Why doesn't this element appear across all browsers on an iPhone?

Tags: html, css, ios

In [this](https://templatemo.com/live/templatemo_555_upright) responsive template a button called navbar-toggler appears when the width is below a certain pixel threshold. It works on all resized browsers in desktop, and in LT browsers that are supposed to simulate mobile devices, but not on a real iphone.

On all browsers on an iPhone running the latest iOS the navbar-toggler button is not visible - but the space where it should be can be tapped to reveal the sidebar. How do I make this element appear on the phone?

The full code can be downloaded [here](https://templatemo.com/tm-555-upright). I believe this is the relevant css:

```
/* Hide the leftside bar */
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .tm-sidebar {
        left: -280px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .navbar-toggler {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: rgb(0 102 153 / 0.80);
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        border-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        top: 40px;
        z-index: 10000;
    }

    .navbar-toggler:focus { outline: none; }
    .tm-sidebar.show { left: 0; }
    .tm-sidebar.show .navbar-toggler { left: 280px; }

    .tm-parallax {
        width: 280px;
        left: -280px;
    }

    .tm-section-wrap {
        width: calc(100% - 280px);
        margin-left: 280px;     
    }

    .tm-section {
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
    }

    .tm-text-container { max-width: 100%; } 
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .tm-parallax {
        position: static;
        height: 360px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tm-section-wrap {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

When the element is clicked the show class is added by this js:

```
$(".navbar-toggler").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".tm-sidebar").toggleClass("show");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: _“but it can be tapped to reveal the sidebar”_ - what are you tapping on then - if it doesn’t display in the first place? Does the whole button not display - or is perhaps just the three line “burger” missing? The only content of that button appears to be a fontawesome icons - do those work on the rest of the page in general on these devices?

Comment: I'm tapping on the space where I know the button should be, and it works as expected: the sidebar appears. The fa icons are used all over, and they all appear properly on the phone. One weird thing is if I "pinch" the phone browser enough, then I can see the fa-bars icon, but when I release the pinch it flickers for one frame at full width then disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting `overflow:visible` on the container, like so:

```
.tm-sidebar{
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Maybe this is caused by different implementation of `overflow` on `fixed` elements. Let me know whether this works.

Comment: Nice to hear. Can the bounty be closed or do you need more info?